# Dynamic Checkbox MS Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, ms-access-2013

I would like to create a form, where checkboxes are created dynamically depending on the records of another table.

Example:

```
Source Table content:
ID     Name
1      ABC
2      DEF
3      GHI
4      JKL
```

I would like that the form will generate `4 checkboxes` on loading.

How to achive this?

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish this would be to use a subform. Say the main form is named [frmTest]. Create a table named [frmTest_CheckBoxItems] with the following fields:

```
[Seq]: Long Integer, Primary Key  
[Description]: Text(255)  
[Selected]: Yes/No
```

Then you could add a Continuous Forms subform to [frmTest] that includes the [Selected] (Check Box) and [Description] (Text Box) fields.

In the `Form Load` event of the main form [frmTest] you could load the values from the [SourceTable] into the [frmTest_CheckBoxItems] table with code like this:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    ReloadCheckBoxItems
End Sub

Private Sub ReloadCheckBoxItems()
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database
    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    cdb.Execute _
            "DELETE FROM frmTest_CheckBoxItems", _
            dbFailOnError
    cdb.Execute _
            "INSERT INTO frmTest_CheckBoxItems (Seq, Description) " & _
            "SELECT ID, [Name] FROM SourceTable", _
            dbFailOnError
    Set cdb = Nothing
    Me.frmTest_CheckBoxItems_subform.Requery
End Sub
```

With a bit of tweaking to the format of the subform (hide the Record Selectors, Navigation Buttons, borders, alternating background colours, etc.) your layout ...

[image: DesignView.png]

... combined with data in [SourceTable] ...

```
ID  Name
--  ----
 1  ABC
 2  DEF
 3  GHI
 4  JKL
```

would look like this:

[image: FormView1.png]

Add another row to [SourceTable] ...

```
ID  Name
--  ----
 1  ABC
 2  DEF
 3  GHI
 4  JKL
 5  AAA
```

... and the next time you open [frmTest] you'll get

[image: FormView2.png]